# Parse lines from messages in a Splunk query to be displayed as a chart on a dashboard

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I generate events on multiple computers that list service names that aren't running. I want to make a chart that displays the top offending service names.

I can use the following to get a table for the dashboard:

```
ComputerName="*.ourDomain.com" sourcetype="WinEventLog:Application" EventCode=7223 SourceName="internalSystem" 
| eval Date_Time=strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") 
| table host, Date_Time, Message, EventCode
```

Typical Message(s) will contain:

```
The following services were not running after 5603 seconds and a start command has been sent:
Service1
Service2
```

```
The following services were not running after 985 seconds and a start command has been sent:
Service2
Service3
```

Using regex I can make a named group of everything but the first line with `(?<Services>((?<=\n)).*)`
However, I don't think this is the right approach as I don't know how to do a valuation for the chart with this information.

So in essence, how do I grab and tally service names from messages in Splunk?

Edit 1:
Coming back to this after a few days.
I created a field extraction called "Services" with regex that grabs the contents of each message after the first line.
If I use `| stats count BY Services` it counts each message as a whole instead of the lines inside. The results look like this:

```
Service1 Service2 | Count: 1
Service2 Service3 | Count: 1
```

My intention is to have it treat each line as its own value so the results would look like:

```
Service1 | Count: 1
Service2 | Count: 2
Service3 | Count: 1
```

I tried `| mvexpand Services` but it didn't change the output so I assume I'm either using it improperly or it's not applicable here.

Comment: Please tell us more about the use case.  What do you want the output to look like?  What do you mean by "valuation"?

Comment: Hey RichG
The use case would be a sharable visual dashboard on Splunk to show other teams or management what monitored services aren't starting on their own after a reboot. If there are problematic services (in the example above, Service2) then they'd be shown with a much higher representation on the graph.

Comment: Ideally I'd just take the top 10 offenders and make a bar graph that counts the number of times it sees each service appear in a time frame. Using the above it would be:
Service2: count 2 Service1: count 1 Service3: count1

By valuation I just mean parsing each event and adding the services reported to a count for the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with the `stats` command.

```
| stats count by service
```

will give a number of appearances for each service.  You then can choose the bar chart visualization to create a graph.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using split() and mvexpand to solve this problem.
This is what worked in the end:

```
My search
| eval events=split(Service, "
")
| mvexpand events
| eval events=replace(events, "[\n\r]", "")
| stats count BY events
```

I had to add the replace() method because any event with just one service listed was being treated differently from an event with multiple, after the split on an event with multiple services each service had a carriage return, hence the replace.

My end result dashboard chart:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Chart dropping down that is clean:

```
index="yourIndex" "<searchCriteria>"  | stats count(eval(searchmatch(" 
<searchCriteria>"))) as TotalCount 
count(eval(searchmatch("search1"))) as Name1 
count(eval(searchmatch("search2" ))) as Name2 
count(eval(searchmatch("search3"))) as Name3 
| transpose 5
| rename column as "Name", "row 1" as "Count"
```

Horizontal table example with percentages:

```
index=something "Barcode_Fail" OR "Barcode_Success" | stats 
count(eval(searchmatch("Barcode_Success"))) as SuccessCount 
count(eval(searchmatch("Barcode_Fail"))) as FailureCount             
count(eval(searchmatch("Barcode_*"))) as Totals | eval 
Failure_Rate=FailureCount/Totals |eval Success_Rate=SuccessCount/Totals
```